# Why do modules use classes in puppet (instead of defines)

Tags: puppet

I've been creating a couple of classes (in different modules) for puppet. Both, separately, require maven. So both classes have something like the following:

```
    class { "maven::maven":
        version => "3.0.5"
    }
```

(using the https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/maven module from puppet forge)

But, if I have one node that has both of my classes, puppet complains because class 'maven::maven' is declared twice. I feel like each of my classes should be free to declare all of the things it needs. If a node has more than one class both of which require maven, then I don't see the problem.

So, my question is: was the author of that maven module wrong to use a class, should he have used a define instead? (because you can use/call/whatever a define multiple times). It appears that if he had used a define I would be able to have the block of code as many times as I like, so if he was right to use a class, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I think the rationale behind this is best explained in [John Arundel's Puppet 3 Beginner's Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=Sbkr6mg-FzAC&pg=PT252&lpg=PT252&ots=RlpbTgBcqG&sig=ZvTjomvRfppkdkMsSSJWh40sn2o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RkuKUt_DLKH7yAHCnoCIDg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> So if you're wondering which to use, consider:
>
> - Will you need to have multiple instances of this on the same node
>     (for example, a website)? If so, use a **definition**.
> - Could this
>     cause conflicts with other instances of the same thing on this node
>     (for example, a web server)? If so, use a **class**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in parameters to a class, there is a possibility of a conflict, the problem being that it is not clear which sets of parameters will get used.

If your first module required maven with `3.0.5` but your second module required maven with `3.0.6`, puppet would not know which one to use.

The puppet module, in making it a class and not a resource/defined type, does not handle the resolution as well, because it was probably intended for a single install.

Puppet currently only supports re-using class declarations without parameters, ie. `include maven::maven`.

Finally, declaring dependencies on other modules in your own module is a tricky thing, that I do not know how to fully resolve yet.